# Where have the google Espresso issue tracker issues gone?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I have a bunch of links to old espresso issues (e.g. https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/issues/detail?id=45), but when I visit them, it tells me

> Project "android-test-kit" has moved to another location on the Internet.

It also says

> View the project at: https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/

The link they provide to view the project at doesn't help. There is no issue tracker on that website.

It doesn't say where the actual issues have moved! I have google around for the location, but I can't find it. It's extremely frustrating that google would change the URL without redirecting to the new issue. Has anyone found the place they're keeping the new issues, and would you be able to find the equivalent of https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/issues/detail?id=45?

Comment: The page tells you it has moved to [github](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/). Easy to google, too.

Comment: @323go that website contains no issues as far as I can tell. I've googled around and have not found it anywhere.

Comment: The closest places I've been able to find that match it are: https://github.com/skyisle/android-test-kit/issues/45, https://github.com/misyobun/android-test-kit/issues/45, https://github.com/xiezefan/android-test-kit/issues/45, but none of those are maintained by google, and they haven't been updated for a year or so. I want the official google issue tracker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espresso has become a part of the AOSP and is being tracked in the official [android issue tracker](https://source.android.com/setup/report-bugs) under the [Test-Support-Libraries](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192735%2B) component.

They labeled all outstanding issues from the old tracker with [Android-Test-Kit-Bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192735%2B%20android%20test%20kit%20bug). It also appears that closed issues from the old tracker didn't make it to the new one

More information on Espresso, including the latest release notes can be found on the [new official](https://github.com/android/android-test) page.

Comment: Thanks. Now how could I find an issue given the url of a now-defunct issue tracker issue? e.g.: https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/issues/detail?id=45

Comment: They labeled all outstanding issues from the old tracker with [Android-Test-Kit-Bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=label%3AComponent-Test-Support-Libraries+%5BAndroid-Test-Kit-Bug%5D&colspec=ID+Status+Priority+Owner+Summary+Stars+Reporter+Opened&cells=tiles) . It also appears that closed issues from the old tracker didn't make it to the new one.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'm adding that comment to your answer because it's very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Workaround - I've found several github clones of the espresso library

i.e. https://github.com/xiezefan/android-test-kit

If you go to the `/issues` tracker on these repositories, you may be able to find the issue, though it likely won't be up to date.

e.g. `https://github.com/xiezefan/android-test-kit/issues/45`

From there, you can either google the issue name, or search for it on the [AOSP tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/) to get the updated status on the issue.

Comment: So it seems they have moved to the AOSP tracker? https://code.google.com/p/android/ but there is no straightforward way to find the url of the new issue given the url of the old one?

Answer (score 0):

The issues are available on their git repository. You can find it [here](https://github.com/android/android-test/issues). They might not have ported all issues to github.

The link to the issue you provided is also cached by the Wayback Machine of the internet archive [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140330093412/http://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/issues/detail?id=45).

Comment: The git link you provided for the is for a repo of an HTML website, not for the test library code. The wayback machine helps a bit, but my main issue is that I need to find the up-to-date issue tracker so I can see if something has been resolved or not, and read the latest comments